# Should I approve edits which remove commented out code?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

This [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5034283) has the comment *"removed a commented out line. If copied into own project it was confusing!"*. The user has removed a single line of code which was commented out.

I am not sure what I should do with this type of edit?

For clarity:

- I am aware of the the language in which the answer was provided.
- I understand of that line of code too.
- If the code stays there, and some user copies it directly, then also it'll remain commented in their IDE.
- A user with basic knowledge of that language wouldn't get confused by that line.

What should I do here? [image].

While I was asking this question, the edit was approved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it tides up the answer somewhat, so I probably wouldn't reject it. There's no harm in making things better, by however little. If there's a large amount of commented out code (not applicable here) then I will normally remove it, unless it has an obvious purpose - it can make reading the post quite difficult.

I probably wouldn't have bothered making the edit in the first place though - especially since the answer doesn't explain why it exists. If I knew enough to use it in my project I like to think I would add an explanation for others; or write my own answer that explained everything thoroughly.